# Como puedo hacer una operacion en la consulta para que me muestre un resultado en c#

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Crear consultas con SELECT que muestre valores calculados en c# ya sea una combinacion de suma y multiplicación, con valores ya creados en una base de datos

llevo esto en codigo:

```
        private void Resultados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable tbl1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Cadenaconexion1 = "Server=localhost;User id=root;Database=Odontologia;Password=;";


    
        MySqlConnection Conexion1 = new MySqlConnection();
        
        MySqlCommand comandobus1 = new MySqlCommand();
        comandobus1.Connection = Conexion1;
        MySqlDataAdapter com1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT porcentaje  FROM CuadroMorfologico", Cadenaconexion1);
      
        com1.Fill(tbl1);
        label1.DisplayMember = "porcentaje";
        
        Conexion1.Close();
        label1.DataSource = tbl1;
        

    }
```

se que en mysql workbench se puede hacer la operacion atravez de un select pero como se haria en c# aplicando tambien unselect para hacer la operacion atraves de datos almacenados en mi base de datos

Comment: Veamos, el porcentaje es un valor que se calcula por lo que no es necesario tenerlo un campo en tu BD que se llame porcentaje. Si es calculable, no se necesita más nada. Ahora, supongamos que quieres hacer una suma de dos campos: 

`SELECT campoA + campoB FROM tuTabla`

Si quieres multiplicar dos valores: 

`SELECT campoA * campoB FROM tuTabla`

Si quieres hacer uso de ambos: 

`SELECT (campoA + (campoB * campoC)) FROM tuTabla`

Comment: el problema esque tiene que ser asi porque el usuario inserta un porcentaje que se almacena en la base de datos y en base al valor agregado calculo el porcentaje que se muestra en una nueva ventana a traves de un textview derivado de un form nuevo